# How can I execute a python file whose name is passed as a string in a shell script?

Tags: python, shell

I have a script `run.sh` with the following contents.

```
for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do
    KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)
    VALUE=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f2- -d=)   
    
    case "$KEY" in
    
            gpu_num)            gpu_num=${VALUE} ;;
            data)               data=${VALUE} ;;
        *)   
    esac  
done

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=${gpu_num} python train.py --data $data
```

I can then run the `train.py` python file by executing the following command.

```
./run.sh gpu_num=0 data="kit"
```

How can I also pass the python file to be executed as a string? For example

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=${gpu_num} python ${python_file} --data $data
```

and

```
./run.sh gpu_num=0 python_file="test.py" data="kit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for ARGUMENT in "$@"
do
    KEY=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f1 -d=)
    VALUE=$(echo $ARGUMENT | cut -f2- -d=)   
    
    case "$KEY" in
    
            gpu_num)            gpu_num=${VALUE} ;;
            data)               data=${VALUE} ;;
            python_file)        python_file=${VALUE} ;;
        *)   
    esac  
done

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=${gpu_num} python $python_file --data $data
```